# Using a variable in a try-catch-finally statement without declaring it outside

Tags: python, scope

I'm pretty new to Python, here is some code I am looking at:

```
try:
    connection = getConnection(database)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("some query")
except:
    log.error("Problem.")
    raise
finally:
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

Is that being cleaned up properly?

In other languages I have written in, I am used to doing something like this:

```
connection = None
cursor = None

try:
    connection = getConnection(database)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("some query")
except:
    log.error("Problem.")
    raise
finally:
    if cursor is not None:
        cursor.close()
    if connection is not None:    
        connection.close()
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Python does not have block scope. Anything defined inside the `try` block will be available outside.

That said, you would still have a problem: if it is the `getConnection()` call that raises the error, `cursor` will be undefined, so the reference in the `finally` block will error.

Comment: Right, I hope this makes sense, but "how far out" is it available? I will assume that a function would contain it, what about if statements and loops?

Comment: If that whole block is within a function, it's available from then on until the end of the function. If it's at module level, it's available globally within that module. If statements and loops do not introduce new scope.

Comment: I feel like this answer needs one more sentence! Something like "so your second example is a valid way to implement this pattern", assuming that is true.

Answer (score 12):

I'd suggest using contexts, like:

```
from contextlib import closing

try:
    with closing(getConnection(database)) as connection:
        with closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
            cursor.execute("some query")
except:
    log.error("Problem")
    raise
```

This should ensure the closing (see [more here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing)).
In some cases, you won't even need `closing` since connection is most likely to support the context protocol itself, so that would be just `with getConnection(database)...`