# How to make a variable inside a try/except block public?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, try-except

How can I make a variable inside the try/except block public?

```
import urllib.request

try:
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    text = page.read().decode('utf8')
except (ValueError, RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
    print("Unable to process your request dude!!")

print(text)
```

This code returns an error

```
NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

How can I make the variable text available outside of the try/except block?

Comment: What will be `text` if `page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)` will raise an exception? If you want to set it with some value you can do it in the except scope or outside the `try except` block.

Comment: `text` is the  be the markup of the url.

Comment: In the `except` case `text` is *never assigned*. You could set `text = None` in that block or before the `try`. This isn't a scope problem.

Comment: if the error mentioned in the question is raised without going through the print statement in the except block then, I think the exception is not getting caught

Comment: // , According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195569/using-a-variable-in-a-try-catch-finally-statement-without-declaring-it-outside, Python does not have a block scope.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

`try` statements do not create a new scope, but `text` won't be set if the call to `url lib.request.urlopen` raises the exception. You probably want the `print(text)` line in an `else` clause, so that it is only executed when there is no exception.

```
try:
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    text = page.read().decode('utf8')
except (ValueError, RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
    print("Unable to process your request dude!!")
else:
    print(text)
```

If `text` needs to be used later, you really need to think about what its value is supposed to be if the assignment to `page` fails and you can't call `page.read()`. You can give it an initial value prior to the `try` statement:

```
text = 'something'
try:
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    text = page.read().decode('utf8')
except (ValueError, RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
    print("Unable to process your request dude!!")

print(text)
```

or in the `else` clause:

```
try:
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    text = page.read().decode('utf8')
except (ValueError, RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
    print("Unable to process your request dude!!")
else:
    text = 'something'

print(text)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a default value for `text` in case there is an `exception`. so maybe updating this answer with default value outside the `try except` scope or inside the else will help him.

Comment: In the last snippet `text` will always eventually be assigned `'something'` if no exception

Comment: "try statements do not create a new scope" this cleared up a lot of things for me, +1

Comment: the "else" clause didn't work for me, but the initial value did. :D

Comment: In the 3rd example, aside from the problem mentioned by @4xy, `print(text)` would still cause the original `NameError` if `page.read().decode('utf8')` raises an exception. It would only work if `text = 'something'` is moved into the `except` block.

Comment: Thank you! This one line "text won't be set if the call to url lib.request.urlopen raises the exception." cleared up the confusion I had for ages!

Answer (score 8):

Just declare the variable `text` outside `try` `except` block,

```
import urllib.request
text =None
try:
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    text = page.read().decode('utf8')
except (ValueError, RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
    print("Unable to process your request dude!!")
if text is not None:
    print(text)
```

Comment: // , Why would this be necessary? Python does not have a separate block-level scope for this `try` and `except`, AFAIK, and according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195569/using-a-variable-in-a-try-catch-finally-statement-without-declaring-it-outside.

Comment: @NathanBasanese It may be necessary, if your try/except block resides in a loop and your except block contains the `continue` statement without defining the variable there.

Answer (score 8):

As answered before there is no new scope introduced by using `try except` clause, so if no exception occurs you should see your variable in `locals` list and it should be accessible in current (in your case global) scope.

```
print(locals())
```

In module scope (your case) `locals() == globals()`