# using try and except for searching urls using google api in python

Tags: python, google-api, except

I want to search urls in a list, which add up to approximately 74 urls. I used try and except to tell python skip sites that do not respond (with http error code 400, etc.)

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey='keyhere')

for i in range(0,k-1):
    try:
        queries = search_sources[i]
        res = service.cse().list(q= queries, cx='idhere',).execute()
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        continue
```

but the problem is that I get the message about some sites has error (which means that except part is not working):

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 838, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2FgktvnmChina+protest&alt=json&cx=myid&key=mykey returned "Bad Request">
```

Comment: Try a more generic `except` line.  Eg `except Exception:` .

Comment: @SonofaBeach just posted the whole error

Comment: it says googleapiclient.errors.HttpError so use that in except

Comment: You should probably just do `for queries in search_sources:` instead of manually manipulating `i` as an index.

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch the correct HttpError. Read the trace.

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:
```

So import that

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError as GoogleHttpError
```

then

```
except GoogleHttpError:
```

Comment: Thanks. The code worked, but I'm not getting anything for res?

Comment: I'm just answering the asked questions question. Don't know how that library works, but it also looks like you aren't using or checking the res value within your loop

Answer (score 0):

According to the `raise` line in your exception output, I think the exception handler you want would be:

```
except HttpError:
    continue
```

EDIT:  You'll need to import this exception, similar to @cricket_007 answer.

Or just use the generic:

```
except Exception:
    continue
```

Comment: I get "HttpError" not defined

Comment: For that one, the code worked but I'm not getting any results for res

Comment: Do you mean you don't get a `res` value when there is an exception, or when there is not an exception?  You certainly should not get a `res` when there is an exception.

Comment: yes it's strange. I do res and I get message >>> res
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'res' is not defined

Comment: You need to post your code of where you're using `res`.  Is it out of scope (and therefore not defined)?  Also, see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666853/how-to-make-a-variable-inside-a-try-except-block-public

Comment: i defined res below try:

Comment: But where do you use it?  Is it in the same scope as where you defined it?  Also, if you got an exception on the line you tried to define it, then it is not defined.